# Avoid CASE clause while importing data to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, import

I have to import data from an old schema to a new one, where a column 'career_name' (in table 'users') that used to be a `VARCHAR` now should be an `INTEGER` which is a foreign key to another table `careers`. This way I intend to tipify the data that was stored in the `VARCHAR` column in order to keep integrity in my database.

Actually, I do the following:

1. Create both new tables in the new schema
2. Use `SELECT DISTINCT 'career_name' FROM old_table` in order to obtain all possible values
3. `INSERT` into my new table `careers` the rows obtained above
4. `INSERT` data into my new table `users` using a CASE clause in order to obtain the ID from table `careers` of the corresponding former `career_name` so the relation is created.

Now the problem is the following, the table `careers` is big, so writing one CASE clause for each row in the table in order to import `users` is nearly impossible.

Is there a way to avoid this? I wish I could use my table `careers` as an associative array, where the key was the former `career_name` and the value the row's ID... Thanks!

Comment: This seems straightforward.  Why can't you just join the old data with the new careers table to get the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT into new_Users 
SELECT Users.Name, careers.id
FROM Users inner join careers ON Users.career_name = careers.career_name
```

Because the schema isnt known to me, I am assuming that new_users table has 2 columns which is name and career_id.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to avoid this? I wish I could use my table 'careers' as an associative array, where the key was the former 'career_name' and the value the row's ID... Thanks!

Er... That's what a table *is*, isn't it? Just join to your new careers table to use it as a lookup when doing the insert:

```
INSERT INTO users (blah, whatever, career_id)
SELECT
  old_users_table.blah,
  old_users_table.whatever,
  careers.career_id
FROM
  old_users_table INNER JOIN careers ON old_users_table.career_name = careers.career_name
```

... where `users` is your new users table, `old_users_table` is wherever you're getting the data you want to migrate, and `careers` is your new careers table.